# PHPExcel : generating error due to php output?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

After building my spreadsheet using PHPExcel, I am unable to open the "save as" or "open" dialog. I got the following code snippet right from the examples directory that comes with the PHPExcel library.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(e) {
        $.post('mail.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('.signature-field,.notes').hide();
            //SUCCESS
            $('.successORfail').html(data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".successORfail").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $(".successORfail").empty().show();
                    });
                }, 4500);
        }).error(function() {
            alert("Fatal Error: mail.php not found!");
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**Note:** the code above generates the alert message "Fatal Error: mail.php not found!" that I set up. Other than that, it does not generate any error messages, it does not save or create an excel file.

When I use the following method, without any headers, the excel file is created perfectly, and saves on the server, without any errors:

```
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('MyExcel.xlsx');
```

I would truly appreciate any help with troubleshooting this error, as I have been working on this for a very long time now.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found out that it is returning something, this is the $.post response http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=xjk2NjRZ

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use ajax like this. Why not just do a regular post? The user will be prompted with a save dialog, and after it stays on the same page anyway. Also: your output has some html at the beginning, and then the zip file you want.

Comment: @Maerlyn can't use regular post because users will often need access to the input fields on the page after the form is submitted. Anyways, this works perfectly fine when I am not using php://output therefore, ajax isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, I don't see any justification for doing so. My script stops working properly right after I add php://output. Ajax isn't the problem.

Comment: You get the output correctly, so your script still works, you just don't get the download popup.

Comment: Where does the h1>hello</h1> at the beginning of the response stream come from?

Comment: @Mark, It comes from the beginning of the script. Removing it completely did not change the outcome.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this jquery as well: the problem lies in how js is handling the response, but I'm not a js expert, but there may be some way of redirecting the excel datastream to a new pane with appropriate headers to force a download dialogue

Comment: Try adding , "json" just before closing your ajax post, telling $.post to receive json... then in the mail.php, use json_encode(); on what you echo back. With console.log(data); you should be able to see your output much easier (for instance via the console in chrome developer tools)

Comment: Or what if you alternatively returned the file name, and used javascript to do soemthing like window.open('myfilename.xls');

Comment: @scott = is there any way to send content to an opened window __with__ headers to identify it as an xls file, else it would just get treated as HTML by default

Comment: I think you need to send it to a script not to a window and have the script output the headers, the user won't know the difference anyways and it should solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually cannot do this the way you are attempting to do this.  Javascript by itself cannot initiate a file download on the user's system (due to security issues).  I am aware of at least one jQuery plugin which gives an AJAX-like download experience.  You might check this out:

http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx

Comment: I am aware of the security issues with javascript. I am downloading with PHP not with javascript.

Comment: PHP is serving the download, but you are trying to use javascript to initiate it. Therein lies your problem. The plugin shown gets around this be creating a hidden iframe which is set to the download location (thus forcing the file prompt), while appearing to keep the user on the same page. A fairly decent solution to the problem.